# How can I not stretch out my image button in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

[image: On the iPhone 11]

[image: On iPad Pro]

I have these search bars and image buttons using Xamarin Forms, but the image button is getting stretched out, and I don't know how I can fix it with the XAML set up that I have.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
             Placeholder="Search"
             Text="{Binding SearchText}"
             FontSize="Medium"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             Margin="0,4,0,0"
             VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
  <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
               Margin="4,5,4,4"
               Command="{Binding Filter}" Source="filter.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent"></ImageButton>
</Grid>
```

The problem is, that if I set the image button to a specific width, to make it universal among devices, I don't know how to tell XAML to just stretch the search bar up to the image. What can I do?

Comment: Aspect = "AspectFit" should do the trick

Comment: For the search bar or image? Or the layout?

Comment: look at Jason Answer

Comment: Have you tried setting the last columnDefinition to Auto?  like this:
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais That isn't working either...

Comment: Based on Recardo's code, add "WidthRequest" for ImageButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried with shared code , however it works in my local site . I think difference should be the `PNG` image . To clearly show the size of the `ImageButton`, I added a background color to illustrate it.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Placeholder="Search"
                Text="{Binding SearchText}"
                FontSize="Medium"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="4,5,4,4"
                    Source="search.png"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"></ImageButton>
</Grid>
```

The effect as follow :

[image]

Here is the `PNG` image info :

[image]

However , I can reproduce your problem with my `PNG` image . If I set  `Aspect="Fill"` and `Width` of `Column` is `*` as follow :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Placeholder="Search"
                Text="{Binding SearchText}"
                FontSize="Medium"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Aspect="Fill"
                    Margin="4,5,4,4"
                    Source="search.png"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"></ImageButton>
</Grid>
```

The effects ：

[image]

About **Solution** , I have found three here :

**First** , if you can get a standard PNG file as minie , there will no problem .

**Second** , you can add `Aspect="AspectFit"` into `ImageButton` as Jason's suggestion .But that's not enough for your `PNG` image .You also need to set `Width` for its `Column` as follow :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Placeholder="Search"
                Text="{Binding SearchText}"
                FontSize="Medium"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    Margin="4,5,4,4"
                    Source="search.png"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"></ImageButton>
</Grid>
```

The effect :

[image]

**Third** , based on my reproduced code , adding `HorizontalOptions="Center"` for `ImageButton` also can solve it .

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Placeholder="Search"
                Text="{Binding SearchText}"
                FontSize="Medium"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Aspect="Fill"
                    Margin="4,5,4,4"
                    Source="search.png"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"></ImageButton>
</Grid>
```

The effect :

[image]

**Although** the image of three solutions shows the same , however the `Bounds` of their backgroud `Frame` is different .

Comment: Thank you! Setting the width the same as my height did the trick

Answer (score 0):

use the [Aspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton#imagebutton-appearance) property

```
<ImageButton Aspect="AspectFit" ...
```

Comment: The button still looks stretched out on the iPad